# Reusing the fields in Elastisearch Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using elastic search 1.6.0.
Here is my aggregation query :

```
GET /a/dummydata/_search

    {
       "size": 0,
       "aggs": {
          "sum_trig_amber": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "TRIGGER_COUNT_AMBER"
             }
          },
          "sum_trig_green": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "TRIGGER_COUNT_GREEN"
             }
          },
          "sum_trig-red": {
             "terms": {
                "field": "TRIGGER_COUNT_RED"
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Is there any way by which i can add three sum_trig_amber + sum_trig_red + sum_trig_green ?

Comment: Hey @Andrei Stefan,  do you know something about this?

Comment: What do you mean by `add three sum_trig_amber + sum_trig_red + sum_trig_green`? Can you give an example?

Comment: Lets assume sum_trig_amber = 10 ; sum_trig_red = 20; sum_trig_green = 30. Now i want the sum of these three which is 60. I am using ES Version 1.6.0.

Comment: `terms` aggregation doesn't do a sum. Maybe you wanted to use another aggregation/

Comment: okey.I am looking for feature like bucket_sum available in ES 2.0.0

Comment: That doesn't exist in 1.x obviously. If you can explain this requirement from a different angle (and not referring to bucket sum) we can think about another approach.